# need to parse DOM xml using JAVA ADT

Tags: java, xml, dom

hello there i am trying to do a project for my university and i need to know how to write and read an xml file 
i tried to read other awnsers but i didnt get anything as iam beiginner in booth java and DOM .... the structure of needed xml is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <cours lang="F" code="info404">
    <Enseignant nom="A. Hellani"/>
    <classe nom="INFO M1 F"/>
    <seances>
      <seance>
        <jour>1</jour>
        <salle>33</salle>
        <temps>1</temps>
      </seance>
      <seance>
        <jour>1</jour>
        <salle>33</salle>
        <temps>1</temps>
      </seance>
    </seances>
  </cours>
  <cours lang="F" code="math 200">
    <Enseignant nom="N. Ajram"/>
    <classe nom="MATH L2 F"/>
    <seances>
      <seance><jour>2</jour>
      <salle>40</salle>
      <temps>6</temps>
    </seance>
    <seance><jour>6</jour>
      <salle>33</salle>
      <temps>2</temps>
      </seance>
    </seances>
  </cours>.
.
.
. 
</xml>
```

Comment: you need to include what you have done until now so people can help you with specific problems

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reproduce a bunch of introductory material here (or coding a solution for you), I suggest that you read a tutorial on XML processing in Java.

A good place to start is one of these Oracle documentation pages:

- [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) which is part of the Java tutorial, or
- [XML Parsing for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm) which is part of the Oracle Database Documentation.

---

<sub>I should point out that the terminology in your question is wrong.  DOM stands for Document Object Model and is the name for a commonly used in-memory representation for an XML document ... *after it has been parsed*.  So "parsing an XML DOM" doesn't make sense.  Also, parsing something "using Java ADT" doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you mean ADT in the sense of Abstract Data Type, you might as well have said "using Java".</sub>

Comment: thanks i will see these tutorials and sorry for the mistakes its just one week i started learning java and android developpment